# Displaying information from a windows service in asp.net web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows, service, web

What i want to do is running a windows service (c#) which gathers some information which i want to display in my asp.net web forms site. The windows service has a timer so that code can be run periodically.

The purpose of my application is to manage windows services (restart, check if they are stuck etc.). Furthermore there is the exact same monitoring service on a different server which checks the other one (monitoringService1 monitors monitoringService2 + some normal services and vice versa). This is why the monitoringService is a service too.

Can you guys give me any hints how i can pass my data from the win service to my web forms?
Thank you in advance!

best regards, 
r3try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the data from the results of your Windows Service in a log or a database, then read the same data from your asp-net application. I would recommend the database way.

Comment: hmm thank you for your proposal, i will look into that...
but is there no way to just remotely call methods and passing the data as arguments?
sorry, im pretty new to this... :/

Comment: @user1226742 the best way to assure both your Windows Service and your asp-net application are using the same data, in this case, would be with a database result. Another way may be use WCF Services or Web Services that runs in the PC where the Windows Service is, but this will just add more complexity to your problem. I would keep with the database idea in mind and give it a try.

Comment: named pipes or COM interop anyone? Yea database seems best I suppose. Depends on your polling interval needs. Is the data "live" aka memory only? Use pipe.